# Threejs Using objects from 3ds Max with textures

Tags: webgl, three.js, 3dsmax

I purchased 3d human teeth model from turbosquid in a 3ds scene format. All I want to do is to extract individaul teeth from the file and use them in threejs script to display them on web page. What I did was exported one tooth from 3ds Max in .obj format and converted that to json using the converter provided with threejs. Though the image appears on the page but with no textures applied to it.
I am new to 3ds Max and Threejs having no idea what am I missing. Can you please guide me.

**Edit:**
Here is the Json metadata

```
"metadata" :
{
    "formatVersion" : 3.1,
    "sourceFile"    : "toothz.obj",
    "generatedBy"   : "OBJConverter",
    "vertices"      : 1636,
    "faces"         : 1634,
    "normals"       : 1636,
    "colors"        : 0,
    "uvs"           : 1636,
    "materials"     : 1
},

"scale" : 1.000000,

"materials": [  {
"DbgColor" : 15658734,
"DbgIndex" : 0,
"DbgName" : "Teeth",
"colorAmbient" : [0.584314, 0.584314, 0.584314],
"colorDiffuse" : [0.584314, 0.584314, 0.584314],
"colorSpecular" : [0.538824, 0.538824, 0.538824],
"illumination" : 2,
"opticalDensity" : 1.5,
"specularCoef" : 70.0,
"transparency" : 1.0
}],
```

**Edit:**
Here's the complete code

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);

loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "js/JsonModels/toothz.js", function( geometry, materials ) {
    materials[0].shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.scale.set( 3, 3, 3 );
    mesh.position.y = 0;
    mesh.position.x = 0;
    scene.add( mesh );
} );

camera.position.z = 340;

//var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
//scene.add( ambient );

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
scene.add( directionalLight );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function render() {
     requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 
} 
render();
```

Comment: You are not providing sufficient information. Can you post a live example using the current three.js version r.53?

Comment: I have included code in question. Plz check

Comment: ensure you are not breaching the max texture of your browser. http://www.browserleaks.com/webgl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Texture exporting is usually tricky in many exporters because there isn't always a clear mapping between 3d program materials and three.js materials. Furthermore, there is no materials defined at all in the .obj file, but a separate .mtl is required. I'm not sure if a) .mtl is exported and b) obj converter uses it, but in any case, your JSON is missing the texture definition in the material. You have a few choices:

1. Try [the MAX exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/utils/exporters/max/ThreeJSExporter.ms), which should allow exporting your stuff directly to JSON, without the intermediate .obj step.
2. With the OBJ route, you should check that all relevant options in the exporter are checked, a .mtl file is generated, and the obj converter finds it.
3. Alternatively add the texture manually into the JSON: `"mapDiffuse": "my_texture_filename.jpg"` (into the material definition in the `"materials"` section of the file).
4. You could also add the texture to the material in your model loading callback. However, this is a big hack and not recommended.

Comment: The texture is applied using Gradient Ramp (3ds Max 2009). I guess we won't have a .jpg for that.

Comment: You should be able to bake any procedural materials into images in any decent modelling program.

Comment: MAX indeed by default exports .mtl files when it writes .obj files.

Comment: For people having trouble with VRayMtl, here are the changes you need to add to the Max script to make it work: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/893#issuecomment-20929994

Answer (score 3):

See the three.js [Migration](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) wiki.

Geometry no longer has a materials property, and loader callbacks, which previously had only a `geometry` parameter, are now also passed a second one, `materials`.

EDIT: You need to do something like this:

```
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "js/JsonModels/toothz.js", function( geometry, materials ) {
    materials[0].shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.scale.set( 3, 3, 3 );
    mesh.position.y = 0;
    mesh.position.x = 0;
    scene.add( mesh );
} );
```

three.js r.53

Comment: That went over my head :) but thanks for your time let me study the concepts again and implement it the way you suggested. Seems like most of the tutorial/documentation on web regarding THREEJS is outdated.

Comment: One very simple question. Do I have to export the texture separate or only the exported/converted object (tooth) is suffice to look in webpage the way it looks in 3ds Max (with all the colors and textures)

Comment: Sorry, I realized that I am using three.js r.52. Let me do it with r.53 and see.

Comment: Still same result. The image look grey without any colors. I have edit the original post to include all my code.